# tabBarIcon not displayed on createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Since I updated react-navigation (from v2 to v3), the icons I had in my createBottomTabNavigator no longer appear above the labels. When I look at the documentation I can not find the solution. Can you help me please ?

The code of my bottom navigation :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    createAppContainer,
    createBottomTabNavigator,
    createStackNavigator,
    createSwitchNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import PronosticsScreen from "../screens/PronosticsScreen";
import BookmakersScreen from "../screens/BookmakersScreen";
import StatsScreen from "../screens/StatsScreen";
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import {Platform} from "react-native";

const PronosticsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Pronostics: PronosticsScreen,
});

PronosticsStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Pronostics',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? `ios-paper${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
                    : 'md-paper'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const BookmakersStack = createStackNavigator({
    Bookmakers: BookmakersScreen,
});

BookmakersStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Bookmakers',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? `ios-paper${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
                    : 'md-paper'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const StatsStack = createStackNavigator({
    Stats: StatsScreen,
});

StatsStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Stats',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? `ios-paper${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
                    : 'md-paper'
            }
        />
    ),
};

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Pronostics: PronosticsScreen,
        Bookmakers: BookmakersScreen,
        Stats: StatsScreen,
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            showIcon: true,
            activeTintColor: '#c7943e',
            activeBackgroundColor: '#000000',
            inactiveTintColor: '#c7943e',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
        },
    });

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Bottom: BottomTabNavigator,
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
```

Moreover, my IDE tells me that the tabBarIcon property is not used..

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the icons exist still by those names. I noticed that many of my `-outline` icons no longer existed by that previous name.

[image]

Comment: The icons exist

Comment: can you provide the code for `../components/TabBarIcon`

Answer (score 0):

your IDE is right, tabBarIcon is not being used, since those are the navigationOptions of a stacknavigator, wich doesnt have tabBarIcon property .You should delete them and then in your createBottomTabNavigator do this for every screen

```
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Pronostics: {
      screen: PronosticsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Pronostics',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={
                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                    ? `ios-paper${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
                    : 'md-paper'
            }
        />
        ),
      },
    },
        Bookmakers: BookmakersScreen, //repeat
        Stats: StatsScreen,//repeat
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            showIcon: true,
            activeTintColor: '#c7943e',
            activeBackgroundColor: '#000000',
            inactiveTintColor: '#c7943e',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
        },
    });
```

[Source](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/StacksInTabs.js#L97)